# Java Spring Security unrecognised roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

The task is to create a Web Application that should be accessible from different users with different roles. Some roles see all pages, some see only a few.

I have the following config for the SecurityConfig, but it's not working.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(value = { SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.class })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   DataSource dataSource;

   @Autowired
   private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       Md5PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
       auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
  }

   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login", "/page1").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('RADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/login", "/page2").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/page2").hasAnyRole("RADMIN", "ADMIN")
    .and().formLogin()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

    }

}
```

I've tried changing `hasAnyRole()` to `hasAnyAuthority()`, no effect. Pretty much every change I make either doesn't let ADMIN to login (he only sees /403 or /404) or lets anyone, authorised or not, to see everything.

Comment: Standard Spring Security authorities start with `ROLE_`, so those should be `ROLE_RADMIN` and `ROLE_ADMIN`, unless you defined your own [`AccessDecisionVoter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionVoter.html).

Comment: Tried that, no difference...

Comment: You did check that `ROLE_ADMIN` was assigned to the user, right?

Answer (score 1):

Well... the problem was as stupid as it can get.

Seems like with one of the commits the database name was changed, thus there was no role (`ROLE_NONE`) to authenticate...

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Spring-Security 4.0.1.RELEASE` and there are two important tables which are `users` and `authorities`. Table `authorities` should have exactly two columns (username, authority) and the role should be with prefix `ROLE_` e.g. `ROLE_ADMIN` & `ROLE_RADMIN` like Andreas pointed out.

Try to keep your authentication simple like below and see does it make any difference then add the additional pages and the roles, e.g.

```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().
        anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll().and().exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/403.html");
   }
```